# Input into variable to return string from array

Tags: python, arrays

```
if opt == ("1"):
    print("Please enter Menu Item Number and table number")
    i = input("Menu Item: ")
    **n** = raw_input("Table Number: ")
    print( "\n" + "Order Details:" + "\n" + "\n" + "Menu Item: " + **items[n]** + "\n"  + "Table Number: " + n + "\n")
```

Trying to use a variable to get a string from an array

Comment: `n` is a string here, e.g. `"4"`. You need to turn it into an integer, i.e. `4`

Comment: Welcome to SO. You may want to read [ask] and [mcve] and edit your question accordingly.

Comment: What is the issue, exactly? I don't see a question here.